# using Rxjava with flatmap not change the downstream data

Tags: kotlin, rx-java, rx-java3

```
RxJava3
Kotlin
```

I have the following method and I am trying to control the downstream to return the `Pair<Customer, Profile>` after the map operator

However, after the first flatMap the data is changes to `customer`. Basically, I want to return the Pair<Customer, Profile> and not the customer dowwstream.

```
override fun execute(): Single<Pair<Customer, Profile>> {
        return Single.fromObservable(
            graphQLProfileService.getCustomerProfile()
        ).map {
            Pair(
                it.mdc.toCustomer(),
                it.profile
            )
        } /* Single<Pair<Customer, Profile>> */
            .flatMap { /* it: Pair<Customer, Profile> */
                updateProfileUseCase.execute(topsCustomer = it.first)
            }
            .flatMap { /* it: Customer */
                updateUserUseCase.execute().toSingleDefault(it) /* it.first, as the first item will be customer */
            }
            .flatMap { /* it: Customer */
                updateAppUseCase.execute().toSingleDefault(it) /* it.first */
            }
}
```

I think the solution should be something like this but I haven't managed to get it to work:
https://medium.com/@douglas.iacovelli/rxjava-kotlin-keep-the-original-value-in-a-flatmap-bbd6a6974a99

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put those `flatMap`s inside a `flatMap` and once they succeed, you have to replace their results back to the value by ignoring it and concatenating with a `just` of the pair:

```kotlin
Single.fromObservable(
    graphQLProfileService.getCustomerProfile()
).map {
    Pair(
        it.mdc.toCustomer(),
        it.profile
    )
}
.flatMap { original ->
    Single.just(original) // <--------------------------------------
    .flatMap { /* it: Pair<Customer, Profile> */
        updateProfileUseCase.execute(topsCustomer = it.first)
    }
    .flatMap { /* it: Customer */
        updateUserUseCase.execute().toSingleDefault(it) /* it.first, as the first item will be customer */
    }
    .flatMap { /* it: Customer */
        updateAppUseCase.execute().toSingleDefault(it) /* it.first */
    }
    .ignoreElement() // <--------------------------------------
    .andThen(Single.just(original))
}
```